# Can I use Datasucker without icebreakers?

Tags: android-netrunner

I've got a [Datasucker](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/01008). Can I use its ability "Hosted virus counter: Rezzed piece of ice currently being encountered has -1 strength until the end of the encounter" even if I do not have any icebreaker with strength equal or greater than ice's currently encountered?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no restriction on using the ability aside from what's printed; you must be encountering a rezzed piece of ice. Datasucker is not an icebreaker, so the strength of the ice doesn't affect the ability. There are reasons to do this, such as [Parasite](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/01012)